# What is the purpose of these capacitors in this State Variable Filter schematic?

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor, active-filter

I need some help understanding this schematic. It's a state variable filter based parametric equalizer. What are the capacitors C4, C5 and C6 for? Are those coupling capacitors like C1 and C7? Are they necessary? Because, if I simulate the schematic without them, I still get the same function.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are DC blocking capacitors, to keep the whole circuit AC coupled.  In particular, they keep any DC current from flowing in the 'frequency' pots, which could cause audible scratching when the knob is adjusted.  If you look at the circuit, the only ground references are at R11 and R14.

The reason it simulates OK is probably because your simulator has all matched op-amps (you could try leaving them out and then doing a Monte Carlo simulation on the op-amp offsets), and because the sound of a DC-biased pot being adjusted isn't something you can simulate.

Comment: Would you happen to know, how to calculate the frequencies? I know how to calculate f_max. It's simple: f_max = 1/(2*pi*C2*R9). But I don't know how to calculate f_min.

Comment: It should be in the neighborhood of \$f = \frac{1}{2 A \pi C_2 R_9}\$, where \$A\$ is the gain (always less than 1) of the voltage divider formed by \$VR_{3A}\$ and \$R_{12}\$ (and by symmetry, the other voltage divider, too).  It'll be affected somewhat by the setting of \$VR_2\$, but I'd have to actually, like, *think* to tell you how in detail.